# Get first and last day of the week in Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

how can you get the first and last day of week. **But my first day should be Monday and last day should be Sunday (I should follow the UK timezone).**

Here is the code from Gortonington.

> %%[
>
> ```
> SET @Today = FormatDate(NOW(), "dddd")
>
> SET @Month = FormatDate(Now(), "mm") /* or "MMMM" if you want full month name */
> SET @Year = FormatDate(Now(), "YYYY")
> SET @Day = FormatDate(Now(), "dd")
>
> IF @Today == "Sun" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = @Day
>     SET @DayEnd = Add(@Day,6)
>
> ELSEIF @Today == "Mon" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = Subtract(@Day,1)
>     SET @DayEnd = Add(@Day,5)
>
> ELSEIF @Today == "Tue" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = Subtract(@Day,2)
>     SET @DayEnd = Add(@Day,4)
>
> ELSEIF @Today == "Wed" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = Subtract(@Day,3)
>     SET @DayEnd = Add(@Day,3)
>
> ELSEIF @Today == "Thu" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = Subtract(@Day,4)
>     SET @DayEnd = Add(@Day,2)
>
> ELSEIF @Today == "Fri" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = Subtract(@Day,5)
>     SET @DayEnd = Add(@Day,1)
>
> ELSEIF @Today == "Sat" THEN
>
>     SET @DayBegin = Subtract(@Day,6)
>     SET @DayEnd = @Day
>
> ENDIF
>
>     SET @BeginDate = CONCAT(@Month,CONCAT("/",CONCAT(@DayBegin,CONCAT("/", @Year))))
>     SET @EndDate = CONCAT(@Month,CONCAT("/",CONCAT(@DayEnd,CONCAT("/", @Year))))
>
> ]%%
> ```
>
> This is the beginning of the week: %%=v(@BeginDate)=%%
>  This is the
>   end of the week: %%=v(@EndDate)=%%

I have a problem with this every last week of the month and also if the prev month is 30 days only I get negative figure on the first day of the next month.

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect code! I will adjust and correct it so that it can be referenced without issue in the future.

Comment: I provided my updated code below and have updated my blog post and calling out  you and Cameron for your help - (https://gortonington.com/first-and-last-day-of-the-week/). Thanks again for pointing out the inconsistency of my original code! I hate to provide anything that is not quality, so any time you find something 'wonky' on any of my work - please reach out and let me know.

Comment: It's okay. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
%%[
SET @LocalTime = SystemDateToLocalDate(NOW())

SET @today = FormatDate(@LocalTime, "dddd")
IF @today == "Mon" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = @LocalTime
    SET @WeekEnd = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '6','D')
ELSEIF @today == "Tue" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '-1','D')
    SET @WeekEnd = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '5','D')
ELSEIF @today == "Wed" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '-2','D')
    SET @WeekEnd = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '4','D')
ELSEIF @today == "Thu" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '-3','D')
    SET @WeekEnd = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '3','D')
ELSEIF @today == "Fri" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '-4','D')
    SET @WeekEnd = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '2','D')
ELSEIF @today == "Sat" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '-5','D')
    SET @WeekEnd = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '1','D')
ELSEIF @today == "Sun" THEN
    SET @WeekStart = DateAdd(@LocalTime, '-6','D') 
    SET @WeekEnd = @LocalTime
ENDIF
]%%
Today is: %%=FormatDate(@LocalTime, "MM/DD/YYYY", "", "en-US")=%%<br>
Start of the Week is: %%=FormatDate(@WeekStart, "MM/DD/YYYY", "", "en-US")=%%<br>
End of the Week is: %%=FormatDate(@WeekEnd, "MM/DD/YYYY", "", "en-US")=%%<br>
```

> **Output**: 
> Today is: 10/04/2019
>  Start of the Week is: 09/30/2019
>  End of the Week is: 10/06/2019

**Reference**:
[FormatDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm)
[DateAdd](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateAdd.htm)
[SystemDateToLocalDate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/SystemDateToLocalDate.htm)

Comment: This is a great solution and thank you for providing an alternative to alleviate the gap from my incorrect code.

Comment: Thank you Cameron!!

Comment: I used to use this method, works great because you can't really do enumerations in ampscript.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my updated code that I am going to be using to replace my incorrect code from now on. This lets you set what day you want the week to begin and then correctly calculates the dates from there.

**(but please give all +1's to @CameronRobert)**

```
%%[

SET @dayofWeekBegin = "Mon"

SET @Today = FormatDate(NOW(), "dddd")

SET @daysOfWeekString = "Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat"

SET @daysOfWeekRowset = BuildRowSetFromString(@daysOfWeekString, '|')

IF @Today == @dayofWeekBegin THEN

    SET @BeginDate = FormatDate(NOW(),'mm/dd/yyyy')

ENDIF



FOR @i = 1 TO Rowcount(@daysOfWeekRowset) DO 

    SET @tempDay = Field(Row(@daysOfWeekRowset,@i),1)

    IF @dayOfWeekBegin == @tempDay THEN

        set @daySub = @i

    ENDIF

NEXT @i


FOR @a = 1 TO Rowcount(@daysOfWeekRowset) DO 

    SET @tempDay = Field(Row(@daysOfWeekRowset,@a),1)

    IF @Today == @tempDay THEN

        set @dateOffset = SUBTRACT(@a, @daySub)

    ENDIF

NEXT @a


IF @dateOffset != 0 THEN

    SET @dateOffsetBegin = SUBTRACT(@dateOffset, ADD(@dateOffset,@dateOffset))
    SET @dateOffsetEnd = SUBTRACT(6,@dateOffset)

ENDIF

IF EMPTY(@BeginDate) THEN

    SET @BeginDate = FormatDate(DateAdd(Now(),@dateOffsetBegin,'D'),'mm/dd/yyyy')

ENDIF

IF EMPTY(@EndDate) THEN

    SET @EndDate = FormatDate(DateAdd(Now(),@dateOffsetEnd,'D'),'mm/dd/yyyy')

ENDIF

]%%
Day of Week Begin %%=v(@dayofWeekBegin)=%%<br>
Today %%=v(@Today)=%%<br>
Day Sub %%=v(@daySub)=%%<br>
Date Offset %%=v(@dateOffset)=%%<br>
Date Offset Begin %%=v(@dateOffsetBegin)=%%<br>
Date Offset End %%=v(@dateOffsetEnd)=%%<br>
This is the beginning of the week: %%=v(@BeginDate)=%%<br>
This is the end of the week: %%=v(@EndDate)=%%<br>
```

Which will output:

```
Day of Week Begin Mon
Today Fri
Day Sub 2
Date Offset 4
Date Offset Begin -4
Date Offset End 2
This is the beginning of the week: 09/30/2019
This is the end of the week: 10/06/2019
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gortonington!!